# is it possible to define a class field recursively?

Tags: python

Is there a way to express the following? I'd like to define a classwise static field called `nullNode`.

```
class Node:
  
  nullNode = Node(0)  # this says "Unresolved reference 'Node'"
  
  def __init__(self, i):
    self.i = i
```

Comment: You can't create an instance of the class while the class is not fully initialized.

Comment: So how should I write the above code? I'd like to be able to reference `nullNode` as `Node.nullNode`.

Comment: `@staticmethod`

Comment: Give us more context about what you actually want to do with it? It looks like you're trying to pass a default arg to the `__init__()` method, but it's more Pythonic to do `def __init__(self, arg=0)` Also, in Python naming convention you'd call it `null_node` not Java-style `nullNode`.

Comment: I'd like to create a singleton instance called `null_node`

Comment: @JRR: ok then please click edit on the question above and add that crucial information. (Comments are ephemeral,likely to disappear, and don't get indexed for search or retrieval).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you're trying to do it a kind of singleton instance (not really a singleton class, but something in the area). One way to solve that would be:

```
class Node:
  
    _nullNode = None

    @staticmethod
    def nullNode():
        if Node._nullNode is None: 
            Node._nullNode = Node(0)
        return Node._nullNode
  
    ... 
    # other methods
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you believe you want a classwise static field called nullNode, but that sounds like kludging a default instance. (Unless your intent is a singleton class as other people have said.)

Give us more context about what you actually want to do with it?

It looks like you're trying to pass a default arg to the `__init__()` method, but it's more Pythonic to simply do:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, i=0):
        self.i = i
```

Of course, this is not a singleton, so you could have multiple instances:

```
node_n_a = Node()
node_n_b = Node()

node_n_a is node_n_b
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it afterwards:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

Node.null_node = Node(0)
```